# string.replace not working?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have code below in my controller:

```
public emailfileclass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            stdctrl=controller;

             quoteId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
             bill= [Select Name from AcctSeed__Billing__c where id=:quoteid limit 1];
             Adattach= new set <id>();
             AddAtt= new List <Attachment>();
                           eTemp= new EmailTemplate();

          eTemp= [Select e.Subject, e.DeveloperName, e.Body, e.ApiVersion From EmailTemplate e
          Where DeveloperName = 'Prof_Billing_Email'];

           //eTemp.subject.replace('{!AcctSeed__Billing__c.Name}', 'TESTTEST');

            subject='Test'+ eTemp.subject;
            subject.replace('Test', 'STOP');


            system.debug ('**********Subject:'+ subject);
            system.assert(subject.contains('STOP'));
```

When I print my subject in debugging, it doesn't have the 'STOP' string and also, system.assert fails. What's going on?

FYI- my subject `string= Test Invoice {!AcctSeed__Billing__c.Name}` from

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The replacement does not modify the string in place, but rather returns the modified value.

Instead of:

```
subject.replace('Test', 'STOP');
```

Use:

```
subject = subject.replace('Test', 'STOP');
```